# Where is the public_html directory in my DreamHost account?

Tags: web-hosting, ftp

I would like to setup https://github.com/NamelessMC/Nameless version 1.0.21 on my DreamHost web hosting. I tried following this guide, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3u8RThdflY. However, when I use SFTP to login, the only directories I see are `Maildir`, `logs` and `<mydomain>.com`. Inside `<mydomain>.com` is just `favicon.ico` and `favicon.gif`. No `public_html` or anything.

In the guide he drags the NamelessMC folder into public_html and sets the htaccess to

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Can someone help me figure out how I can get this working on my site, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<mydomain>.com` folder **is** your web root.

The `public_html` name has become the common name a lot of shared hosts use as their web root directory. I would assume this stems mainly from cPanel calling the web root directories `public_html` but in reality it is just the set directory that the web server is configured to use as its web root. It doesn't actually need to be named `public_html`.

---

Dreamhost says the following:

> I fully-hosted my domain. Where is the public_html?
>
> When adding hosting to fully host your domain, you are prompted to
> enter a web directory. This directory is where you place the content
> on your web server. Drop in your index file in the web directory so it
> displays when you visit your page. This web directory is the same as
> your "public_html" folder.